Docker swarm ingress flip flopping while accessing container application
I am facing very strange issue with docker swarm ingress implementation. I am running 3 node cluster of docker swarm, I have opened required ports for docker swarm and ingress. For testing purpose, I am deploying nginx service with 2 replicas. But when I am trying to access nginx url from another server, it works one time and fails another time like flip flopping. Earlier I suspected if this is related to firewall but even I stopped firewall on all 3 servers, still issue persists. In tcpdump, I can see the syn and ack packets when it is working but when it fails tcp dump only shows syn packets. On this cluster single container and docker compose containers works fine. Below are the few details.
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens192
  sources: 163.202.101.0/24
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 7946/tcp 7946/udp 4789/udp 2377/tcp 25315/tcp 4010/tcp 2780/tcp 2781/tcp 80/tcp 8080/tcp
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

public
  interfaces: ens192
  sources: 163.202.101.0/24
trusted
  interfaces: docker0

NETWORK ID     NAME              DRIVER    SCOPE
6578c94f08aa   bridge            bridge    local
94cd91123447   docker_gwbridge   bridge    local
f95a8e594c75   host              host      local
sb6agp0or02q   ingress           overlay   swarm
8ieatmyf72pe   nginx_default     overlay   swarm
2ef710766885   none              null      local

